# Recursive Trigger is not working

Tags: trigger

I have a trigger in my Org.

```
trigger test on test__c(Before Insert,Before Update,after Update,after Delete,after Insert) {
    If(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isUpdate){
         testmethod pp = new testmethod(Trigger.new);
         pp.testingcall(Trigger.new,Trigger.oldMap);
}
        If(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){
          testmethod pp = new testmethod(Trigger.new);
          pp.testing(Trigger.new,Trigger.oldMap);}
```

After My recursive method apex class is added:

```
public class checkRecursivecall {
     Public static Boolean firstcall=false;
}
```

Now Recursive trigger is added:

```
trigger test on test__c(Before Insert,Before Update,after Update,after Delete,after Insert) {
    

If(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isUpdate){
      if(!checkRecursivecall.firstcall){
        checkRecursivecall.firstcall = true;
         testmethod pp = new testmethod(Trigger.new);
         pp.testingcall(Trigger.new,Trigger.oldMap);
  }
}
            If(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){
              if(!checkRecursivecall.firstcall){
              checkRecursivecall.firstcall = true;
              testmethod pp = new testmethod(Trigger.new);
              pp.testing(Trigger.new,Trigger.oldMap);
}
}
```

Now Recursive trigger method is added , but still not working for insert and update? what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe it is a better idea to ask a question about the actual problem that you are trying to solve, before you try something complicated as recursive triggers.

Comment: My actual problem trigger should have to run only once, as Derek explained , if process builder / workflow rule update again , it should not call the trigger second time

Answer (score 8):

"It's not working" doesn't tell us much about what the issue is (we don't know how it's supposed to work unless you tell us or if it's simple enough). A reasonable guess here would be something along the lines of "my code is running before update, but not after update".

In addition, your description of "recursive" may not be correct. Running `before update` and then `after update` isn't recursion, it's part of the normal execution flow. You'd experience trigger recursion if you were to perform a dml update on the same records that are currently in `trigger.new`. Salesforce may prevent running `update trigger.new` (because that's a pretty good indicator that you're setting yourself up for an infinite loop), but the point is that ***trigger recursion is when you operate on the same records multiple times***.

We could extend that to include situations like insert triggers on an object that insert more records of the same object. The main problem we're trying to avoid is infinite looping. For sake of ease, let's agree that "recursion" in this sense just means "looping at least twice"

### There is a lot of bad advice surrounding handling of recursion in triggers

The simplest recursion handling mechanism is to have a `static Boolean firstRun` in an apex class (because static variables in a trigger are useless, they get reset between `before` and `after` contexts, as well as between each chunk of (up to) 200 records).

**You should not use a static Boolean to (attempt to) control trigger recursion**

This is objectively the worst handling mechanism, and I'd argue even worse than having no recursion handling. With no handling, you'll eventually run into an error/exception and records will generally be rolled back.

With a simple, static boolean, the first time your code is called will be fine, but...

- If you have workflow rules or a process builder process that cause the trigger to be run again, the trigger work will not be done (which may or may not be desireable)
- If you have more than 200 records taking place in a DML operation, your trigger will not perform work on anything beyond the first 200 records
- If you have more than 200 records, you'll have no idea that some records won't be updated unless you log that (and have a habit of reading through logs) or someone else comes up to you and says "my record wasn't updated like it should have been". This is a *silent failure*
- If you have before update *and* after update work, the after update work will not be run (*I suspect this is the primary issue you're facing*)

I may go so far as to say that people who suggest this approach obviously do not know what they are doing and you should be very wary of taking advice from them.

### A better (but still not perfect) approach

A much better approach is to maintain a `static Set<Id> alreadySeen`.

Usually, when people talk about preventing recursion, a more accurate description would be to say "once I process this record once, I don't want to perform the same work on it again". The focus is on records that you have *already seen*.

Provided you have a class with that static variable available, you would use it like so

```java
trigger MyTrigger on My_SObject__c(<before/after contexts here>){
    // Copy the trigger context variable so we can remove the records we've already seen
    // We can't add/remove records from Trigger Context Variables directly, but we can
    //   from a clone
    // The clone also ensures that we're still working on the same instance of the record stored
    //   in the TCV, so updating a record in this map in a "before" trigger context still
    //   gives us the benefit of updating the value without DML
    Map<Id, My_SObject__c> toBeProcessed = trigger.newMap.clone();

    // Remove the records we've already seen
    toBeProcessed.keySet().removeAll(Recursion.alreadySeen);

    // We're left with a Map of records that this is our first time seeing
    // Add the Ids to the set of Ids we've seen (so that we don't work on them again)
    Recursion.alreadySeen.addAll(toBeProcessed.keySet());

    // Do your work
}
```

The shortcomings of this approach are:

- It doesn't work for insert triggers (before insert, we have no Id. It should normally be impossible for a record to go through an insert trigger more than once anyway<sup>1</sup>)
- It doesn't work if you have work to do in both `before update` and `after update` (when we get to `after update`, the record has already "been seen" and so is ignored)
- It still doesn't play nicely with workflow field updates
- If you're running an `allOrNone = false` DML operation (e.g. `Database.update(records, false);` and you hit a validation rule that causes some records in the first chunk of 200 trigger records to fail, Salesforce will auto-retry that trigger chunk (with the problematic records removed) but does not reset static variables. In that situation, even the first chunk of 200 records will not be processed (because according to the static variable, we've already seen them)
- If you insert new records for object X in an update trigger for object X, you can still loop infinitely (though using a checkbox field or doing work in the `after insert` trigger to make sure that further records are not created can mitigate this)

### I still haven't been able to come up with the ideal recursion prevention mechanism

The next step up from a `Set<Id>` would be something like a `Map<System.TriggerOperation, Set<Id>>` that would allow you to differentiate between seeing records in before/after update contexts.

It still doesn't play nicely with workflow field updates (ideally, you'd be able to determine whether or not a workflow field update counts as "recursion" or not), nor with `allOrNone = false`.

Salesforce doesn't provide us with a standard way to determine if we're running again because of workflow or if we're retrying a trigger chunk in an `allOrNone = false` operation, but it is possible to infer if we are in such a situation.

<sup>1: At least under typical circumstances. `allOrNone = false` comes into play here as well. If there are validation errors on insert, allOrNone will retry the insert like it will retry updates. The problematic part for us is that Ids aren't available until after insert begins running, and the automatic retry will end up assigning *different ids* for the successful records (compared to the first run)</sup>

Comment: @SFDC I encourage you to take your time to read my answer so you understand the considerations that need to be made here. Read it several times if needed. I think the example I provided with a `Set<Id>` is simple enough and has enough comments for you to apply it to your own case. You'd be passing the `toBeProcessed` map (or maybe the list you'd get from calling `.values()` on the map). The `Map<System.TriggerOperation, Set<Id>>` approach is what I'd reccommend, and should be a relatively simple step up from the `Set<Id>` implementation.

Comment: @SFDC as always, you should try to work it out on your own first, and then come back to us if you get stuck and have a specific question.

Comment: * You'd be passing the `toBeProcessed` map to the subsequent method calls instead of passing `Trigger.new` and the like. By doing that, you'll only be performing work on records that have not yet been encountered (assuming that you're managing the static collection appropriately). The core idea behind the Set and Map approaches is that they remove things that have already been processed from `toBeProcessed`. In normal cases, that'll mean that `toBeProcessed` ends up being empty (when running through the trigger again).